# How to create an index/ranking per group in javascript for an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an index per each category, based on how many observations are in each category. I have the following array of objects:

```
[
  { "country": "A", "category": "A" },
  { "country": "B", "category": "A" },
  { "country": "B", "category": "B" },
  { "country": "B", "category": "B" },
  { "country": "B", "category": "B" }
];
```

I would want to get this:

```
[
  { "country": "A", "category": "A", "id":1},
  { "country": "B", "category": "A", "id":2},
  { "country": "B", "category": "B", "id":1},
  { "country": "B", "category": "B", "id":2},
  { "country": "B", "category": "B", "id":3}
];
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to present an _attempt_ you made yourself at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this result. If you wanna go with vanilla js you can use a combination of the array functions reduce, concat.

As shown in this codesandbox sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-swartz-0071z?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried with map and push, but totally missed using reduce!

Comment: Yeah no problem. Always keep reduce in mind as a last resort - you can do practically any transformation of the array with it

Answer (score 0):

If you know the items in this array will be in the correct order you can use something like this:

```
let arrayOriginal = [{country: "A", category: "A"},
 {country: "B", category: "A"},
 {country: "B", category: "B"},
 {country: "B", category: "B"},
 {country: "B", category: "B"}]

let counter = 1;
let arrayModified = arrayOriginal.map((item, index, array) => {
  if(index > 0){
    if(item.category == array[index-1].category){
      counter = counter +1;
    } else {
      counter = 1
    }
  }
  item.id = counter;
  return item;
})
```

Its just a simple map function that compares current item with the previous one and if they both have the same category it adds 1 to counter.

You can check the result in here: https://codepen.io/gregorvonvitek/pen/LYLVGVJ?editors=1111